# ABCPDF 8 does not generate page when jsapi corechart is used

Tags: .net, google-visualization, abcpdf, jsapi

I am using ABCPDF 8 for .NET to generate PDF.

```
Doc theDoc = new Doc();
theDoc.HtmlOptions.Engine = EngineType.Gecko;
theDoc.HtmlOptions.UseScript = true;            
theDoc.Rect.Inset(20, 20);
int theID = theDoc.AddImageHtml(html, true, 600, true);
```

The PDF generates fine. Although I added google charts to the page:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        google.load("visualization", "1.0", { packages: ["corechart"] });
    </script>
```

Now PDF generation hangs on AddImageHtml method.
Note that the HTML itself (with charts) is displayed fine in the browser.

Answer (score 0):

Javascript (which Google Charts, of course, requires to do anything) is disabled by default when rendering pages.  See the [UseScript Property](http://www.websupergoo.com/helppdfnet/source/5-abcpdf/xhtmloptions/2-properties/usescript.htm). You may also need or want to use the [Engine property](http://www.websupergoo.com/helppdfnet/source/5-abcpdf/xhtmloptions/2-properties/1-engine.htm) to set the engine to Gecko for a more accurate rendering.